# Command working from terminal but not from PHP

Tags: linux, terminal, php

I can successfully run an executable from the command line, but when I try to do the same thing from PHP with `exec()` the outcome is different.

The command is:

```
ffmpeg -i a.wav -i a.m2v a.mpeg
```

When running from PHP, the Movie Player simply states 'The file contains no playable streams'.

You know why?

Comment: what command are you running?

Comment: the command is 'ffmpeg -i a.wav -i a.m2v a.mpeg'

Comment: and what is the different output ffmpeg is giving you?

Comment: from terminal the output file is a working video. When run from PHP though, the Movie Player simply states 'The file contains no playable streams'.

Comment: But *is* the output generated? And does it have a non-zero file length?

Comment: The output is generated and the file length is non-zero, it contains alot of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the environment variables. Maybe ffmpeg can't find (or can't access due to permission restritions) its resources when you run it from php.

Comment: Good point. The ffmpeg executable is found though and can use the files with right permissions, do you have any other names of the variables?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ffmpeg, maybe it could use some environment variables that point explicitly to the directories where it finds its codecs?

Comment: I'd also investigate if ffmpeg has a "-v" option that you could use to increase its verbosity when you run it from php. Then you could capture the output and investigate it, maybe it will complain there about something that it is missing.

Comment: Solved it! The -v option was indeed useful, i used ffmpeg -v 5 and got useful information. The problem was that ffmpeg terminated after a while, maybe phps' max_exection time, dont know. However, I now run nohup php myfile.php. Thank you!